# Type checking for http-post arguments Python; Using types as values in a dictionary

Tags: python, types, eval

For an API that I'm writing, I'd like to write a 'check_params' method that ensures arguments passed in the body of an http-post request are able to be appropriately typecasted.

For example, suppose I am passing an argument 'latitude'.
Then,

```
    'latitude'='thisisnotafloat'
```

should give an error, while

```
    'latitude'='43.21'
```

should not throw an error.

To handle multiple arguments, is there anything wrong with creating a dictionary with types as the values:

```
    required_types = {
            'arg1':str,
            'arg2':int,
            'arg3':str,
            'arg4':float
    }
```

and then performing duck-typing (for simplification of the question, assume I'm handling the case where a required arg does not get passed in at all and type checking only occurs after an existence check).

```
    for arg, type_ in required_types.iteritems():
        try:
            type_(self.get_argument(arg))    #using tornado here to get body arg
        except:
            handle_invalid_type_error()
```

Alternatively, I could store the types as strings and use the eval() function. 
E.g.,

```
     required_types = {
            'arg1':'str',
            'arg2':'int',
            'arg3':'str',
            'arg4':'float'
    }

    for arg, type_ in required_types.iteritems():
        try:
            eval(type_)(self.get_argument(arg))  #using tornado here to get body arg
        except:
            handle_invalid_type_error()
```

Is there a clear winner here? Or another superior approach?

Comment: I find your first approach OK. You need anyway to cast the input values to their respective types to work with them (i.e. latitude as float, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The recommended ("Pythonic") way to do this is to just do the conversion when you need to, and raise an error if it fails. Unless it's massively inconvenient to deal with an error in a later stage of the program, I wouldn't bother with a `check_params` method at all.

Also, I see absolutely no advantage to storing the types as strings and `eval`ing them. If you were getting the types dynamically, then sure, you could use `eval`, but otherwise it adds an extra processing step that, although it comes at a negligible cost, serves no purpose. and it's generally better to stay away from `eval` unless you *really* need it (just a good mindset to get into from a security standpoint).

Answer (score 1):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912913/type-checking-for-http-post-arguments-python-using-types-as-values-in-a-diction/7912956#7912956) would be my general advice, too.

If you really need to check the arguments beforehand – sometimes there *are* reasons to do so – your first approach is basically fine.  Two comments, though:

1. You shouldn't use a bare `except` clause.  It will also catch exceptions you most certainly don't want to catch here, like `SystemExit`.  In the given example, the bare `except` clause would also catch a `KeyError` (or whatever) resulting from a failing argument look-up, which would probably lead to a rather unhelpful error message.  If the types you are checking for are built-in Python types, catching `ValueError` should be enough.  If `ValueError` isn't enough, `except Exception` is almost always better than a bare `except` clause, since it won't catch `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`.
2. In your example, you also check for `str`.  This will always succeed because the values you are retrieving *are* strings, so it's a bit pointless to check if you can convert them to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could use [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/)?  If not, it might be worth having a look at how it implements validators for your API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't share the same point of view of the other comments (so far). I think that exposing an API that does a proper error checking and report a clear, descriptive error message (or even a list of errors), is a crucial point to get your API used by third parties.

Moreover, you get the validation out of the way once for all and can focus on the real work : the logic.

Now to answer your question:

Have you look at this gist : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/850704 ?

You can validate using a validator function, a type checking, an equality checking. It fits well in tornado if you ever use it to power your API.

If you are looking for something mode declarative, you can have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous#show-me-an-example